# recieve message from port in TCP connection using c#

Tags: c#, tcp

how can I read message from TCP connection port and convert it to string using c#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TcpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx), [TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclient.aspx), [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx), [TcpClient.GetStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream.aspx), [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx), [Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx).

This should get you started. MSDN has plenty examples.